# .htAccess REdirect without 302

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewriterule .* LoadSite.php
```

What I am trying to do is that if the file doesn't exist then call LoadSite.php... this will then load any number of other php files via include (depending on the url).... this works for a GET request, but when the a POST is made, I does a 302 redirect and therefore the script doesn't get the POST variables.  Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see why this would do a 302. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works:

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule (.*) /err.php?reason=404
</IfModule>
```